# OpenCV C++ camera image not being saved to matrix

Tags: c++, opencv, video-capture

I am using openCV 2.4.10 on visual studios 2012 express for desktop on windows 7, 32 bit operating system.

I created a function that initializes a webcam, takes an image and stores it in a matrix, and then returns the image matrix.

```
Mat frameCapture ()
{   
Mat srcCap;
//initializes structure type of cap
VideoCapture cap(0);
if(!cap.isOpened()) 
{
    //check for camera
    cout << "No camera detected" << endl;
    waitKey(10);
}
//stores next frame into matrix
cap >> srcCap;
//check to see the camera took a picture
if( srcCap.empty())
{ 
    cout << "no data in image\n";
}
//return the image matrix
cap.release();
return srcCap;
}

int main ()
{
Mat src;
src = frameCapture();
imshow (window1, src);
waitKey(0);
}
```

So when running the program, it will say "no data in image" meaning that srcCap.empty() returned true and then it will throw an assertion error for the imshow function. However, the program will sometimes run and return an image successfully. Furthermore, when I incorporate the function in a loop for image processing, it will sometimes take a few pictures and then randomly spit out "no data in image" and throw the same assertion error, or it won't take the first picture at all and spits out "no data in image", throwing the same assertion error. The camera is detected every time and cap is opened; the code never says "No camera detected"

My question is what is causing cap >> srcCap to not work, is it a hardware issue? The camera i'm using is a usb 2.0 plugable microscope.

Comment: What happens if you capture more than one frame, e.g. `for (int i=0; i<5; ++i) cap >> srcCap;`? Still empty?

Comment: i haven't tried that, i think the problem might have something to do with the CMOS sensor on the camera being not as sensitive to light as a CCD sensor. But nesting it in a for loop to take more than one picture might solve the problem. I will check it out!

Comment: so it solved the problem, i did it without having to set a finite amount of tries by creating a boolean in the function and using a while loop, checking srcCap.empty() after each capture and if it was successfull than switching the boolean value, should probably add a upper limit too so it doesn't get stuck in an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

I think you that your current program just reads the first frame only. Mostly when reading the camera frame, the first frame may not contain any data.

I would suggest that you use a loop in the main() and read latter frames.

Comment: I noticed this behavior several times as well. Do you have any insight on what is happening in the back?

Comment: I think perhaps it is just part of hardware startup or initalization and messaging phrasing etc. Kinect and many webcam I have tried gives the same blank frame in the first frame.